# Image is not sent to another activity using Intent

Tags: android

I'm trying to send the user post from the adapter to another activity. Here is how I did it:

```
public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull final ViewHolder holder, final int position) {
        firebaseUser = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();
        final Post post= mPost.get(position);
        Glide.with(mContext).load(post.getPostimage())
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image))
                .into(holder.post_image);
 holder.post_image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
 Intent i = new Intent(mContext, PostDetails.class);
 i.putExtra("postimage",post.getPostimage());
   mContext.startActivity(i);
               ((Activity) mContext).overridePendingTransition(0, 0);

            }
        });
}
```

and in the other activity:

```
 postImage = findViewById(R.id.postImage);
   postImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("postimage", 0));
```

this is the Post Model class:

```
  public class Post {
        private String postid;
        private String postimage;
        private String title;
        private String publisher;
        
    
        public Post(String postid, String postimage, String title, String publisher)
        {
            this.postid = postid;
            this.postimage = postimage;
            this.title = title;
        }
        public Post ()
        { }
        public String getPostid() {
            return postid;
        }
    
        public void setPostid(String postid) {
            this.postid = postid;
        }
    
        public String getPostimage() {
            return postimage;
        }
    
        public void setPostimage(String postimage) {
            this.postimage = postimage;
        }
    
        public String getTitle() {
            return title;
        }
    
        public void setTitle(String title) {
            this.title = title;
        }
    
        public String getPublisher() {
            return publisher;
        }
    
        public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
            this.publisher = publisher;
        }
    }
```

Everything looks fine, But the image is not showing in the second activity. With now error message! I don't know what the problem is.

Comment: can u add the modal class of Post class

Comment: I have added it, please take a look

Comment: You are passing a String when you do 
i.putExtra("postimage",post.getPostimage());
While setting you are extracting it as Integer
postImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getIntExtra("postimage", 0));

Comment: check my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
postImage.setImageResource(getIntent().getStringExtra("postimage"));
```

You are passing String value to image Resource but image resource takes Int .

You can use glide to load image , So get Intent from String extra method because you have to get **string** not **int**

```
Glide.with(this).load(getIntent().getStringExtra("postimage"))
                .apply(new RequestOptions().placeholder(R.drawable.loading_image))
                .into(postImage);
```

Comment: I tried your method, it shows the loading image. It should only appear when it is loading not as a the final image.

Comment: use getStringExtra because ur passing string not int, check my updated answer
Hope it helps

Comment: can you see my other post? it is something similar. it is about passing spinner and switch. here it is https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64887914/pass-spinner-and-switch-values-to-another-activity